# jetty plugin is not running properly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jetty, jetty-9, maven-jetty-plugin

I am using jetty 9 to run a jetty project. But I am not able to run this as a standalone or on the server. This is probably because eclipse has left server support after jetty 8. Also getting **support was removed in 8.0**. can anyone help to run the jetty-maven project?

Comment: There is not enough information provided on this question to render any kind of valid answer.   Show your work, what have you tried, what are the error message, etc.  Example: Eclipse supports up to Jetty 11 just fine, so there's something more fundamental at issue here.  But we cannot tell what it is due to lack of information.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. It's showing jetty is running in the eclipse. But now war file getting created.Also, UI is coming as files not as web app. @JoakimErdfelt

Comment: You can edit your question to add more detail.